# How to configure LDAP for ElasticSearch (regular or OpenDistro)?

Tags: elasticsearch, ldap

I am running ES 7.2 (soon 7.3) and want to find a clear way how to authenticate users via LDAP inside the company (via LDAP server that already exists).

Where and what needs to be changed in config files in ElasticSearch side in order to enable LDAP authentication for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Joe, regular (requires ES gold subscription) vs opendistro is the question, it's your call. What are your requirements ? Config depends on it.

Comment: Hi @EricLavault Requirements are to use open source/free software with newest ES version possible and include LDAP.. If you have a good tutorial to how to achieve that with OpenDistro - it would be great!

Comment: Just follow the documentation it's pretty well written. Actually most people struggle with ldap itself, if you need help on that part as well I suggest you add your ldap settings (how do you bind to it,, what is the username attribute that should be usedfor authentication, where or under which base are contained the users in the dit, etc.), then it's just config.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer focusses on the **regular** Elasticsearch use, not OpenDistro:

Since it would be impossible to cover all possible configurations in one answer (imo), I would recommend that you take a look at the official documentations:

[Elasticsearch 7.3 User Authentication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/7.3/setting-up-authentication.html)

[LDAP User Authentication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/7.3/ldap-realm.html)

[Elasticsearch 7.3 Security Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/security-settings.html)

[LDAP Realm Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/security-settings.html#ref-ldap-settings)

There you should get all information needed to set it up.

**EDIT:**

You need to keep in mind that you would need to purchase at least a Gold Subscription in order to use LDAP User Authentication. It is **not** included in the Basic License.

You can see the list of features per subscription [here](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions).

Comment: It looks like above links are for Elasticsearch and X-PACK - which is NOT FREE to use. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, LDAP authentication is not included in the free version. You can see it in the feature list of the respective subscriptions. https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

Comment: But OpenDistro has LDAP and ElasticSearch and IS FREE: https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security-configuration/ldap/ .  You do not recommend OpenDistro to be used for LDAP?

Comment: I updated my answer. It focusses on regular Elasticsearch. I can not answer your question for OpenDistro, sorry.